# mysql two identical tables insert , no primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table with similar and identical structure , lets call them tbl_old and tbl_new.
The table is like follows

```
    deptid usrname amount

    1111   jack    80000

    1111   jill    80900

    2799   tom     70933

    3000   tim     20000

    2799   jill    90000

    8988   mary    70800

    6889   tom     65200
```

I have unique_index on two columns deptid and usrname. 
No two rows can have same deptid and usrname together.

Now i have another table with some data  and I want to insert data in the existing table. 
Data to be inserted from tbl_new to tbl_old in such a manner 
that if deptid and usrname combination is same the row from tbl_new should replace old row.
and if data doesnt exist it should be inserted.

Actually there are several other columns like usramount which i have not mentioned here.
And there are 2 million records in tbl_old and 0.5 million in tbl_new.
Please suggest a mysql query which can run fastest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT
INTO    tbl_old (deptid, usrname, amount, usramount)
SELECT  deptid, username, amount, usramount
FROM    tbl_new
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE  amount = VALUES(amount),
        usramount = VALUES(usramount)
```

Comment: there is hesitation i have in your answer, I have 20 columns and writing all column name will be problematic.. cant i just replace entire row when deptid amd usrname combination is same in two tables ? plz

Comment: @david35: no, you can't. You've made more typing writing your comment than it takes to type 20 columns.